# fatal error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory during cross compile

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

I need to cross compile hostapd,
even after editing makefile to do cross compilation,am getting the above error

Comment: This is not really a Ubuntu question... if you want a useful answer, post which cross-compile packages you installed and the parameter for `./configure`. And this is not a kernel question!

Comment: Nothing about this question makes it seem off-topic, but it is unclear.

Comment: Someone understood what this was about!  +1 to the Answer just because he could make something out of nothing.  Voted to keep open now.

Comment: I still don't like post, where the compiler error message is posted without any other information. But voting it down is also unfair to new users

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about Ubuntu here, the needed header is located in `libnl-3-dev` package (full path will be */usr/include/libnl3/netlink/genl/genl.h*).

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS `hostapd` needs the following build-dependencies:

```
  android-headers android-headers-19 autotools-dev debhelper
  dh-strip-nondeterminism docbook docbook-dsssl docbook-to-man docbook-utils
  jadetex libdbus-1-dev libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libncurses5-dev
  libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-route-3-200 libnl-route-3-dev libosp5
  libostyle1c2 libpcsclite-dev libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libqt4-designer
  libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-help libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools
  libqt4-svg libqt4-test libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev libsgmls-perl
  libsp1c2 libssl-dev libsynctex1 libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libtinfo-dev
  libzzip-0-13 lynx lynx-common openjade po-debconf qt4-linguist-tools
  qt4-qmake sgml-data sgmlspl sp tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-recommended tipa zlib1g-dev
```

You should adjust your build system to satisfy these dependencies.